# Implementing `read` for a left-associative tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm having a hard time implementing [Read](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t:Read) for a tree structure. I want to take a left-associative string (with parens) like `ABC(DE)F` and convert it into a tree. That particular example corresponds to the tree

[image: tree].

Here's the data type I'm using (though I'm open to suggestions):

```
data Tree = Branch Tree Tree | Leaf Char deriving (Eq)
```

That particular tree would be, in Haskell:

```
example = Branch (Branch (Branch (Branch (Leaf 'A')
                                         (Leaf 'B'))
                                 (Leaf 'C'))
                         (Branch (Leaf 'D')
                                 (Leaf 'E')))
                 (Leaf 'F')
```

My `show` function looks like:

```
instance Show Tree where
    show (Branch l r@(Branch _ _)) = show l ++ "(" ++ show r ++ ")"
    show (Branch l r) = show l ++ show r
    show (Leaf x) = [x]
```

I want to make a `read` function so that

```
read "ABC(DE)F" == example
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a situation where using a parsing library makes the code amazingly short and extremely expressive. (I was amazed that it was *so* neat when I was experimenting to answer this!)

I'm going to use [Parsec](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsec) (that article provides some links for more information), and using it in "applicative mode" (rather than monadic), since we don't need the extra power/foot-shooting-ability of monads.

#### Code

First the various imports and definitions:

```
import Text.Parsec

import Control.Applicative ((<*), (<$>))

data Tree = Branch Tree Tree | Leaf Char deriving (Eq, Show)

paren, tree, unit :: Parsec String st Tree
```

Now, the basic unit of the tree is either a single character (that's not a parenthesis) or a parenthesised tree. The parenthesised tree is just a normal tree between `(` and `)`. And a normal tree is just units put into branches left-associatedly (it's extremely self-recursive). In Haskell with Parsec:

```
-- parenthesised tree or `Leaf <character>`
unit = paren <|> (Leaf <$> noneOf "()") <?> "group or literal"

-- normal tree between ( and )
paren = between (char '(') (char ')') tree  

-- all the units connected up left-associatedly
tree = foldl1 Branch <$> many1 unit

-- attempt to parse the whole input (don't short-circuit on the first error)
onlyTree = tree <* eof
```

(Yes, that's the entire parser!)

If we wanted to, we could do without `paren` and `unit` but the code above is very expressive, so we can leave it as is.

As a brief explanation (I've provided links to the documentation):

- [`(<|>)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.2/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#v:-60--124--62-) basically means "left parser or right parser";
- [`(<?>)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.2/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#v:-60--63--62-) allows you to make nicer error messages;
- [`noneOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.2/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Char.html#v:noneOf) will parse anything that's not in the given list of characters;
- [`between`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.2/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v:between) takes three parsers, and returns the value of the third parser as long as it is delimited by the first and second ones;
- [`char`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.2/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Char.html#v:char) parses its argument literally.
- [`many1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.2/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v:many1) parses one or more of its argument into a list (it appears that the empty string is invalid hence `many1`, rather than `many` which parses zero or more);
- [`eof`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.2/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v:eof) matches the end of the input.

We can use the [`parse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.2/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#v:parse) function to run the parser (it returns `Either ParseError Tree`, `Left` is an error and `Right` is a correct parse).

#### As `read`

Using it as a `read` like function could be something like:

```
read' str = case parse onlyTree "" str of
   Right tr -> tr
   Left er -> error (show er)
```

(I've used `read'` to avoid conflicting with `Prelude.read`; if you want a `Read` instance you'll have to do a bit more work to implement `readPrec` (or whatever is required) but it shouldn't be too hard with the actual parsing already complete.)

#### Examples

Some basic examples:

```
*Tree> read' "A"
Leaf 'A'

*Tree> read' "AB"
Branch (Leaf 'A') (Leaf 'B')

*Tree> read' "ABC"
Branch (Branch (Leaf 'A') (Leaf 'B')) (Leaf 'C')

*Tree> read' "A(BC)"
Branch (Leaf 'A') (Branch (Leaf 'B') (Leaf 'C'))

*Tree> read' "ABC(DE)F" == example
True

*Tree> read' "ABC(DEF)" == example
False

*Tree> read' "ABCDEF" == example
False
```

Demonstrating errors:

```
*Tree> read' ""
***Exception: (line 1, column 1):
unexpected end of input
expecting group or literal

*Tree> read' "A(B"
***Exception: (line 1, column 4):
unexpected end of input
expecting group or literal or ")"
```

And finally, the difference between `tree` and `onlyTree`:

```
*Tree> parse tree "" "AB)CD"     -- success: ignores ")CD"
Right (Branch (Leaf 'A') (Leaf 'B'))

*Tree> parse onlyTree "" "AB)CD" -- fail: can't parse the ")"
Left (line 1, column 3):
unexpected ')'
expecting group or literal or end of input
```

#### Conclusion

Parsec is amazing! This answer might be long but the core of it is just 5 or 6 lines of code which do all the work.

Comment: The parsec above works, but also accepts strings like "(AB)C(DE)F" which could never be from the given show instance. In this case read' example == read' "(AB)C(DE)F" is True.

Comment: @ChrisKuklewicz, isn't that correct behaviour? The brackets are just there for grouping; the associativity means that sometimes they are redundant, but they are still allowed to be there.

Comment: Nothing is incorrect here for a Read instance; the only thing in the Haskell 9 report I can find says "Strings produced by showsPrec are usually readable by readsPrec."  I should have written a longer comment to make it clear that I was not calling your parser incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

This very-much looks like a stack structure. When you encounter your input string `"ABC(DE)F"`, you `Leaf` any atom you find (non-parenthesis) and put it in an accumulator list. When you have 2 items in the list, you `Branch` them together. This could be done with something like (note, untested, just including to give an idea):

```
read' [r,l] str  = read' [Branch l r] str
read' acc (c:cs) 
   -- read the inner parenthesis
   | c == '('  = let (result, rest) = read' [] cs 
                 in read' (result : acc) rest
   -- close parenthesis, return result, should be singleton
   | c == ')'  = (acc, cs) 
   -- otherwise, add a leaf
   | otherwise = read' (Leaf c : acc) cs
read' [result] [] = (result, [])
read' _ _  = error "invalid input"
```

This may require some modification, but I think its enough to get you on the right track.

Answer (score 3):

The parsec answer by dbaupp is very easy to understand.  As an example of a "low-level" approach, here is a hand written parser which uses a success continuation to handle the left-associative tree building:

```
instance Read Tree where readsPrec _prec s = maybeToList (readTree s)

type TreeCont = (Tree,String) -> Maybe (Tree,String)

readTree :: String -> Maybe (Tree,String)
readTree = read'top Just where
  valid ')' = False
  valid '(' = False
  valid _ = True

  read'top :: TreeCont -> String -> Maybe (Tree,String)
  read'top acc s@(x:ys) | valid x =
    case ys of
      [] -> acc (Leaf x,[])
      (y:zs) -> read'branch acc s
  read'top _ _ = Nothing

  -- The next three are mutually recursive

  read'branch :: TreeCont -> String -> Maybe (Tree,String)
  read'branch acc (x:y:zs) | valid x = read'right (combine (Leaf x) >=> acc) y zs
  read'branch _ _ = Nothing

  read'right :: TreeCont -> Char -> String -> Maybe (Tree,String)
  read'right acc y ys | valid y = acc (Leaf y,ys)
  read'right acc '(' ys = read'branch (drop'close >=> acc) ys
     where drop'close (b,')':zs) = Just (b,zs)
           drop'close _ = Nothing
  read'right _ _ _ = Nothing  -- assert y==')' here

  combine :: Tree -> TreeCont
  combine build (t, []) = Just (Branch build t,"")
  combine build (t, ys@(')':_)) = Just (Branch build t,ys)  -- stop when lookahead shows ')'
  combine build (t, y:zs) = read'right (combine (Branch build t)) y zs
```