# Parsing math equations

Tags: parsing, math, haskell

Just for kicks, I'm trying to create an application that can simplify, factor, and expand algebra equations. Programming the rules seems as if it will be straight forward if I can get the equations into a good workable format. Parsing the equations is proving to be a hassle, Currently working with Python but I'm not against having to learn something new.

Are there any libraries (for any language) that would make this project pretty simple, or is that a pipe dream?

[Tagging this with Haskell because I have a feeling that's where the 'simple' is]

Comment: Simple? Programming? You must be new to this... ;-)

Comment: You did not define what kind of algebra equations you deal with. AFAIK, for a reasonable definition (with trigonometric, exponential, logarithmic, polynomial functions and their composition) of these, the problem of simplifying them is undecidable.

Comment: Parsing expressions (which use the common operators `+` `-` `*` etc.) rather than equations is fairly easy with the Parsec library in Haskell. Parsec inspired libraries have been created for other languages but perhaps they don't go as far as defining the expression parser kit. Daan Leijen wrote excellent documentation for Parsec including writing an expression parser, unfortunately the manual is now a bit out of date: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/daan/download/parsec/parsec.pdf

Comment: Scala has parser combinators built in.

Comment: "Maxima is a fairly complete computer algebra system written in lisp with an emphasis on symbolic computation." maxima.sourceforge.net. There is a nice GUI called wxMaxima.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Haskell has many many libraries that make writing parsers reasonably easy. [Parsec](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsec) is a good start, and it even has [clones in other languages](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsec#Parsec_clones_in_other_languages), including [Python](http://www.valuedlessons.com/2008/02/pysec-monadic-combinatoric-parsing-in.html) (that article also links to [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) which looks like it might also work).

[This answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408046/implementing-read-for-a-left-associative-tree-in-haskell/10410178#10410178) is an example (note, it's probably not top-notch Parsec or Haskell): it's indicative of the power of Haskell's parsing libraries, precisely 4 lines of code implement the whole parser.

You could also browse old questions and answers to get a feel for the various libraries and techniques, e.g. [parsec](/questions/tagged/parsec), [parsing+haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parsing+haskell) and [parsing+python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parsing+python).

The best way to work out your line of attack for the larger project would be to start small and just try stuff until you're comfortable with your tools: choose a library and try to implement a relatively simple parser, like parsing expressions with just numbers, `+` and `*`, or even just parsing numbers and `+` with bracketing... something small (but not too small; those two examples each have non-trivialities, the first has operator precedence and the second has recursive nesting). If you don't like the library much, try a different library.

Answer (score 4):

It's been done in just about every language.

Python has a library for parsing algebraic equations and symbolic mathematics all ready to go:

http://code.google.com/p/sympy/

I'd recommend reusing, unless your purpose is to learn how to write such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Python or matlab would be my suggestions. Are you planning on storing the whole equation in a string, and then split it up, to factor and simplify?

Give some more information, kindof a cool project.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I'd like to suggest you MathParseKit.

This is a C++ library that given a string like "2*3/4" gives you a Tree of functions/variable/constants that defines the expression.

You can solve it, but you can even change it and put it again in string format.

You can find it at:

https://github.com/B3rn475/MathParseKit