# Building a parser and linking it in Visual C++

Tags: c++, parsing, graph

### Hello stackoverflow community!

I have to do a project for my University. Short put: I need to make a GUI-based program(I chose Visual C++ and the Express compiler for that task) that receives input from an user, like this:

```
x = sin(t)
y = cos(t)
```

These two are the parametric identities. However, we do not know *t*, so in order to get rid of it we would do this:

```
x^2 = sin^2(t)
y^2 = cos^2(t)
-------------  (add the two)
x^2 + y^2 = 1 (eqution of a circle)
```

The idea is that the user can provide much more complicated examples of parametric equations and the program can ultimately get rid of the *t* unknown constant. Afterwards it should also be able to draw the graph of the implicit defined equation on a XOY cartesian. On a plus it should also be able to calculate the first and second derivative of the two parameter equations.

I thought that a parser could do it, but unfortunately I do not know where to start with this idea. If someone could provide me with some resources concerning my requests to learn I would be much grateful.

I have a C++ and JavaScript background (so I don't really start from zero).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you are asking people in stackoverflow to do your homework?

Comment: No, I just need some leading (books, directions) I must present this project so obviously I have to know how the program works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why Express? The [community edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) contains the whole unrestricted (in terms of functionality, not licencing) thing for free.

Regarding interpretation.
Either come up with your own language (using bison/flex for instance, [have a look at an example](http://gnuu.org/2009/09/18/writing-your-own-toy-compiler/)) or embed an existing interpreted language, such as python or lua [(a random example](https://csl.name/post/lua-and-cpp/)).

I've successfully implemented lua as a replacement for a real GUI in some of my own projects and can recommend it, however if you'd like to do some real symbolic math, you'd probably need to come up with a language of your own.

Also have a look at [Parsing math equations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461089/parsing-math-equations) regarding parsing math equations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!