# How to implement a Read instance with the actual parsing already complete, in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408046/implementing-read-for-a-left-associative-tree-in-haskell/10410178#10410178), one finds the statement that it would not be very hard to implement a `Read` instance for the datatype `Tree`, with the actual parsing already complete.

However, I am having a hard time to understand how such a function as `read` works: AFAIK, I should implement a `readsPrec` function instead of `read` and this `readsPrec` should perform the reading for strings consisting of only one character. Is this correct?
If that is the case, then how should one implement a `Read` instance of `Tree` when the parsing is done via `ParsecT`? Can we break the parsing word by word, or is there any need to do so?

I didn't think of `read` as a difficult feature in Haskell, but now I find it quite perplexed and confusing, and I am lost in searching `Hoogle` for all such unfamiliar things as `readP_to_S`, `readS`, etc.

Any help or reference will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The type of `readsPrec` is just `Int -> String -> [(a, String)]`. You can return the empty list to denote a read failure, or the singleton `[(x, "")]` where `x` is the parse result to denote success. If you already have a `Parsec` parser for your type, or any other parser, just run this parser and convert its output to the appropriate form.

Comment: But this `""` looks wrong: it won't return the rest of the string that is not parsed, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been wondering about this for some time, and your question prompted me to look into it.

**Summary:** Easiest way to do it manually:

```
instance Read Tree where
    readsPrec _ str = [(parsecRead str,"")]
```

But `deriving` is the safer option; the above doesn't work with `[Tree]` and other data types. My understanding is that `Show` and `Read` are **not intended to be implemented manually**; they **should be derived** and work on **syntactically correct Haskell expressions**.

---

It looks like the reason that `Read` isn't as simple as

```
class Read a where
    read :: String -> a
```

is that there is system of parser combinators, similar to but distinct from Parsec, that's designed to be modular, recursive, and so on. But since we are already using a different parser combinator library, Parsec, I'd think it's best to mess with the other system as little as possible.

The Prelude documentation says that a minimal complete implementation of `Read` is `readsPrec` or `readPrec`. The latter is described as "Proposed replacement for readsPrec using new-style parsers (GHC only)". This smells like trouble to me, so let's go with implementing `readsPrec`.

The type is

```
readsPrec :: Read a => Int -> ReadS a
type ReadS a = String -> [(a,String)]
```

and the documentation for `ReadS` reads "A parser for a type `a`, represented as a function that takes a `String` and returns a list of possible parses as `(a,String)` pairs". To me, it's not entirely obvious what a "parse" is, but a peek at the [source code for `read` in `Text.Read`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Text.Read.html#read) is revealing:

```
read :: Read a => String -> a
read s = either errorWithoutStackTrace id (readEither s)

readEither :: Read a => String -> Either String a
readEither s =
    -- minPrec is defined as 0 in Text.ParserCombinators.ReadPrec
    case [ x | (x,"") <- readPrec_to_S read' minPrec s ] of
      [x] -> Right x
      []  -> Left "Prelude.read: no parse"
      _   -> Left "Prelude.read: ambiguous parse"
  where
   read' = -- read' :: P.ReadPrec a
     do x <- readPrec
        lift P.skipSpaces -- P is Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP
        return x
```

I tried to expand the definitions of `readPrec_to_S` etc., but I  felt it wasn't worth it. I think the definition makes clear that we should return `[(x,"")]` as a successful parse.

The integer argument to `readsPrec` seems to be the "precedence context". My guess is that it is  safe to ignore it if we just want to parse one tree at a time, but that ignoring it will cause problems later if we try to parse instances of `[Tree]` for example. I will ignore it because I don't think it's worth the trouble.

In short, if we have `parsecRead :: String -> Tree` as defined in the post you refer to (the author called it `read'`)

```
instance Read Tree where
    readsPrec _ str = [(parsecRead str,"")]
```

If we check how this works in a program (using the `Show` instance that the original asker provided):

```
main = do
    print (read "ABC(DE)F" == example)
    print ([read "ABC(DE)F", read "ABC(DE)F"] :: [Tree])
    print (read "[ABC(DE)F,ABC(DE)F]" :: [Tree])
```

we get

```
True
[ABC(DE)F,ABC(DE)F]
Test.hs: Prelude.read: no parse
```

The complexity and lack of documentation here actually makes me think that `deriving (Read)` is actually the only safe option, unless you are willing to dive into the details of precedence levels.
I think I've read somewhere that `Show` and `Read` are actually **mainly intended to be derived**, and that the strings are intended to be **syntactically correct Haskell expressions** (please correct me if I'm wrong). For more general parsing, libraries like `Parsec` are probably the better option.

If you have the energy to look into the source code yourself, the relevant modules appear to be

- [`Text.Read`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Text.Read.html#read)
- [`GHC.Read`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Read.html)
- [`Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP.html)
- [`Text.ParserCombinators.ReadPrec`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Text.ParserCombinators.ReadPrec.html)

Comment: `readsPrec _ str = [(parsecRead str, "")]` seems like a bad idea. It completely ignores parse errors, and doesn't compose well with functions that expect `readsPrec` to return the unparsed bits of the string. And what's more, it's not even necessary to be bad in these ways: parsec is perfectly capable of reporting parse errors and perfectly capable of returning the unparsed part of the input string.

Comment: @DanielWagner That sounds like it would be an improvement! Could you provide an example? I am not very familiar with parsec and I can't find an obvious way to return the unparsed part in the documentation.

Comment: [Here's a proof of concept.](http://lpaste.net/175029) In ghci, `parsecToReads (char 'a' <|> char 'b') "abc"` produces `[('a',"bc")]`.